# Dynamic pages that keep footer and header but replace content?

Tags: spring, templates, model-view-controller, dynamic, thymeleaf

im making a spring boot application with thymeleaf i have a bit of trouble finding a solution for the following.

I want my page to have a directory that follows a template like

```
<header></header>
misc...
<content>
{DYNAMIC}
</content>
<footer></footer>
```

For example at "/posts/{3}" the {DYNAMIC} would be replaced with the content of post with id = 3.

I have researched a bit and i have seen fragments etc but im not sure how i can build them from the server.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried apache tiles ? it's easier to learn then Angular

Comment: Im not using angular or anything js.I want it to be a server side process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Thymeleaf Utraq Dialect to help you create a base template and then use then decorate your blog detail page with the base template.

The base template will have header and footer and provide a dynamic section and the blog detail page will just provide the data for the dynamic section. You can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121576/recommended-template-engine-to-reduce-redundancy-of-dynamic-content-spring-boot/47123581#47123581) on how to use the dialect.

Comment: That's great , although  im not sure how im gonna call this in spring.It returns a string which is the name of the template , which i guess is gonna be the base template.How will then i choose the inside content? Is there an option to return view "X" with fragment "Y" ?

Comment: Spring integration is pretty simple, if you are using only Spring MVC, then you can check out a github project created by me [here](https://github.com/sanaulla123/spring5-blueprints/tree/master/1_world). In the project I configure the Thymeleaf Engine along with the Dialect and created template files in `src/main/resources/templates`

Comment: If you need Spring Boot based integration, its damn simple, But I dont have a sample right now to share with you. In Spring boot you just need to include the thymeleaf spring boot starter and add these two properties `<thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.1.2</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version><thymeleaf.version>3.0.3.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>` so that it picks latest version. Then you can create the same template structure I have created in the Spring MVC sample